# Automated Document Library for Project Management

Tags: document-library

I am looking for an App that will assist me in the following way.

I would like be able to create a folder using the Project Name, then have this app copy the folder structure of a Master Folder.

In the Master Folder strucutre will be a series of documents that requiring renaming, prefacing the file name with the Project Name.

These files are currently .dotx files so the app will need to open them rename them as "(Project Name) - Detailed Design.docx" in order to keep the template formating.

Does anyone know of anything that might assist us here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [Document Sets](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-document-sets-HA101782466.aspx)

It is a folder structure where you define valid file types (with templates linked to them) that can be stored inside. The files inside the folder(document set) can also share MetaData from the parent folder. It is an out of the box resource from SharePoint 2010 and 2013.

Comment: Our sharepoint team is advising that this is not an out of the box requirement.

Comment: I am not explaining things well, The templates files need to be opened so that the templating features can capture the information they are designed to capture.  The file is then to be saved as a document taking the project name (from the folder created title) and preface the file with it.  Saving the document as a docx or doc file an not a template.  This is to be done only referencing the master files, not moving or renaming them in any way.  This will be repeated time and time again when new projects are created.